# How to use paste within group_by (dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following data (example):

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
x <- c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4)
dat <- data.frame(id, x)
```

Now I can count the occurrence of x by group (id) and save in dat2:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(id, x) %>% dplyr::mutate(count = n())
```

Now count cases for the id's:

```
dat2 <- dat2 %>% group_by(id) %>% dplyr::mutate(j = n())
```

This works all fine. Result:

```
dat2

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id     x count     j
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     2     2     2
2     1     2     2     2
3     2     3     2     3
4     2     3     2     3
5     2     4     1     3
```

Now to my problem. I want to use paste within "group_by". To be more exact, i want to use two character-"placeholder" i (for id) and z (for x) to control the grouping. I don't want to use the "real" objects id and x:

```
i <- "id"
z <- "x"

dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(dat[[paste(i, sep = "")]], dat[[paste(z, sep = "")]]) %>% dplyr::mutate(count = n())
```

This first step also works, same as above. However, going into the next final step, an error occurs:

```
dat2 <- dat2 %>% group_by(dat[[paste(i, sep = "")]]) %>% dplyr::mutate(j = n ())

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `..1` is `dat[[paste(i, sep = "")]]`.
i Input `..1` must be size 2 or 1, not 5.
i The error occured in group 1: dat[[paste(i, sep = "")]] = 1, dat[[paste(z, sep = "")]] = 2.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My question: How to avoid this error and get to the same result like before without using paste? Working with the paste command may look strange, but i need to work with a character-placeholder.

I am glad about any help!

Comment: Starting with my example object "dat", i want to create a new variable "count", which counts the occurence of "x" within the two groups defined by "id". Thats the first step. Second step is a new variable "j", which counts the rows within "id". The goal is the dataframe dat2 with "id", "x", "count" and "j" (see above). I want to create the two variables "count" and "j" using two character-objects "i" and "z", which refer to the variable-names "id" and "x". I don't know if using paste is the right way for my problem.

Comment: I updated the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `across` instead of `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
      group_by(across(all_of(c(i, z)))) %>% 
      mutate(count = n()) %>%
      group_by(across(all_of(i))) %>% 
      mutate(j = n())
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
     id     x count     j
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1     2     2     2
2     1     2     2     2
3     2     3     2     3
4     2     3     2     3
5     2     4     1     3
```

---

Or instead of grouping, use `add_count`

```
dat %>% 
   add_count(across(all_of(c(i, z))), name = 'count') %>% 
   add_count(across(all_of(i)), name = 'j')
  id x count j
1  1 2     2 2
2  1 2     2 2
3  2 3     2 3
4  2 3     2 3
5  2 4     1 3
```

Comment: Working with across is an alternative to paste, but it does not solve the problem. The answer refers only to the first step that is described in the problem. In the second step (group_by(dat[[paste(i, sep = "")]]) the error remains, no matter whether with paste or across.

Comment: @C.F. I see only two codes in your post i.e. group_by and mutate(j = n()) what is the second part.  `group_by` with `dat[[paste` is not all recommended

Comment: @C.F. I don't really understand what you are doing with `paste(i, sep="")` i..e `i` is already a character object

Comment: Second solution works for me, thanks a lot. However, the first one with group_by leads to an error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`. x Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column `id` doesn't exist. i Input `..1` is `across(all_of(i))`. i The error occured in group 1: id = 1, x = 2.

Comment: @C.F. Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')` I used `1.0.7`.  These kind of errors are common when we have an older version

Comment: I was on an older version, after updating to 1.0.7 using group_by also works!

Comment: I have one follow-up question to the first solution with "across". What if i want j to be the mean of x, grouped by id, still using i and z to refer to id and x? I Thought about "dat %>% group_by(across(all_of(i))) %>% summarize(j = mean(z, na.rm = TRUE))". However, obviously it doesn't work.

Comment: @C.F. you could change the `summarise` i.e. `summarize(j = mean(!! rlang::sym(z), na.rm = TRUE))` or with `across` i.e. `summarise(across(all_of(z), mean, na.rm = TRUE))` and rename or use `.names` in `across`